# react hook useState throwing TypeError: Assignment to constant variable error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on some code, and I am stuck on this error. I am using the useState hook
when a condition is true, I want to change value & show that value in Input box
I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
I understand that it if you define it as const you cant change its value, but I don't get why.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Demo = props=> {

const [userId, setUserid] = useState('abc1@gmail.com');

 if (regionData === 'us')) {
    userId = 'abc2@gmail.com';
  } else {
    userId = 'abc3@gmail.com';
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-sm-8">
             <input type="text" className="form-control rounded-10" value={userId} name="userid" onChange={(e) => { setUserid(e.target.value); }}  />
    </div>
  )

}
export default Demo;
```

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should see state as readonly, if you need to change it you have to use the setter provided by useState

Comment: and there is something wrong with your code logic, if you reset userid on each render then why do you have a controlled input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing it the first time, why not do it at assignment?

```js
const [userId, setUserid] = useState(
  regionData === 'us' 
    ? 'abc2@gmail.com'
    : 'abc3@gmail.com'
);
```

If you want to update it when `regionData` changes, in that case, you will need to use `useEffect`.

```
const getUserId = () => {
  if (regionData === 'us') {
    return 'abc2@gmail.com';
  } else {
    return 'abc3@gmail.com';
  }
};

const [userId, setUserid] = useState(getUserId());

useEffect(() => {
  setUserId(getUserId());

  // Provided, regionData is a react state coming either 
  // from props or defined in this component
}, [regionData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the state, you should use the setter function instead of assigning a value to a variable.
In your case, this would be the correct approach.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (regionData === 'us')) {
  setUserId('abc2@gmail.com')
} else {
  setUserId('abc3@gmail.com')
}}, [])
```

Also, see react lifecycle methods and `useEffect` hook. In this case, it might be `ComponentDidMount`.

Comment: This will also create an infinite render loop

Comment: Thats why I mentioned lifecycle methods

Answer (score 0):

userId is not to be modified directly.
You will have to update in a useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (regionData === 'us')) {
     setUserId('abc2@gmail.com');
  } else {
     setUserId('abc3@gmail.com');
  }
}, []);
```

if regionData is part of `props`, do pass `regionData` as a dependency to the `useEffect`.

Comment: should add regionData as dependency then, but it's not a good use case of useEffect anyway

Comment: Doesn't seem to be part of the component from the code, hence omitted.

Answer (score -1):

To set userId you need to call setUserId function like this:

```
setUserId('blablabla')
```

You can change the value of a constant variable but not its type.

i.e:

```
const a = 0

a = 100 // no error
a = 'toto' //will throw an error
```

Comment: Both will throw an error

Comment: Can you explain why because on the react document, this is the way you use useState https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: I don't see assigning to a constant variable anywhere in the link you provided

Comment: Why you can't change the value of a constant variable? Because it's constant.

Comment: @Konflex Its giving same error. when I used setUserid('blablabla')

Comment: no @KonradLinkowski you can modify const variable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Where exactly is it written in this article? I see only -  **The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment**